# hashmap variable naming convention: key2Value?

Tags: naming-conventions

After a discussion with a colleague: how well is the inclusion of a `2` in a hashmap variable name considered good practice?
We have a few maps like `id2Name`, `location2Block`. Is this world readable for developers?

Answer (score 0):

Is better to call maps keyToValue or valueByKey, without the 2 because can bring misinformation.

Here you have some examples:
http://softwareas.com/naming-conventions-for-key-value-maps/

Comment: While this link may answer the question, link only answers are discouraged on Stack Overflow, you can improve this answer by taking vital parts of the link and putting it into your answer, this makes sure your answer is still an answer if the link gets changed or removed :)